# Playing Video jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-video

Which jquery plugin is best for playing videos with the following features.

1. Open source and free.
2. Run multiple videos on single page (Must).
3. Automatically stop video after some seconds (Must).
4. Google Ad sense feature (optional).
5. Append HTML in mid of the video so user should able to click the links given in HTML (Must).
6. Should support for YouTube videos (Must).
7. Play/pause/fullscreen basic feature should also include.
8. Good documentation.

Comment: From the off-topic flagging menu: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: My concern is not you to find the plugin/tool basically. My concern is, if you guys has worked on any library which includes all these features, please refer me. I have researched but could not find better solutions. So just wanted some strong technical answer for that. Who has really worked on the same problems and customized the libraries.

Comment: @admdrew Please don't mark the question down, if you feel you can't or don't want to answer the question. I have seen a lot of questions regarding the same and most of people refer best of there knowledge. Stackoverflow Reputation doesn't matters for some people. Please let the other guys to take interest. Hope you understand the question.

Comment: I did not downvote this post, I just flagged it for closure. You say you just want someone to refer you to a tool, which is off topic ("...asking us to **recommend**...").

Comment: @admdrew, sorry for writing you the same. I just need recommendations for that. I just want to write for the people who downvote the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flowplayer is plugin that can be used to fill all requirements and we can set cupoint to stop video after some second and can use plugin to append clickable html as shown below. Add this code in rails html file with url of the video.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.13.js"></script>

<div id="example7" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
<div id="show-text">
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><b>Click here to continue</b></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show-text").hide()
  });

  $f("example7", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
      clip: {
          url: '/system/videos/lesson_uploads/000/000/069/original/Tom_and_Jerry_Cartoon.mp4',
          autoPlay: false,
          autoBuffering: true,
          // set cue point
          onCuepoint: [[30000], function(clip, point) {
            $f().stop()
            var plugin = this.getPlugin("content");
            plugin.show(10000).setHtml($("#show-text").html());
          }]
      },

      // set up content plugin
      plugins: {
          content: {url: 'flowplayer.content-3.2.9.swf', display: 'none'}
      }
  });

  var player = $f()

  player.onLoad(function()  {
      // this- variable points to the player's API
      // this.getScreen().animate({width:300, height:200});
  });


</script>
```